# SQL Need avg from diferent rows with a filter

Tags: sql, average

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve this problem:

"In english : Get the Average of the scores of each student in year 2003."
"Determine el promedio de notas finales de todos los alumnos de la escuela del año 2003."

The result should be something like this : Peter Avg = 7, Johng Avg= 3, etc.

This is as far I got:

`SELECT AVG( "NOT_NOT" ) FROM "NOTAS" WHERE "FECH_NOT" = '2003-02-03'`

Here are the table:

[SCORES Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qisPq.png)
[Students Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qzdi.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT "COD_ALU", AVG( "NOT_NOT" )
FROM "NOTAS" WHERE "FECH_NOT" = '2003-02-03' GROUP BY "COD_ALU";
```

Comment: The code calculates the average per student but as an integer, but I believe that thats the way to go. All I need now is to figure out how to put the student names instead of their Id.

Comment: Thank you I've found the answer: SELECT "ALUMNO"."NOM_ALU", "ALUMNO"."APE_ALU", AVG( "NOTAS"."NOT_NOT" ) FROM "ALUMNO", "NOTAS" 
WHERE "ALUMNO"."COD_ALU" = "NOTAS"."COD_ALU" GROUP BY "ALUMNO"."NOM_ALU", "ALUMNO"."APE_ALU" ORDER BY AVG( "NOTAS"."NOT_NOT" ) DESC

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, it is something like this:

```
SELECT STUDENT, AVG( NOT_NOT*1.0 )
FROM NOTAS
WHERE FECH_NOT >= '2003-01-01' AND FECH_NOT < '2004-01-01'
GROUP BY STUDENT;
```

Comment: The code calculates the average per student but as an integer, but I believe that thats the way to go. All I need now is to figure out how to put the student names instead of their Id.

Comment: @Computer . . . You need to join to another table to get that information.

Comment: Oh, and how I could do that?

Comment: Thank you for yoru reply, I found the answer: SELECT "ALUMNO"."NOM_ALU", "ALUMNO"."APE_ALU", AVG( "NOTAS"."NOT_NOT" ) FROM "ALUMNO", "NOTAS" 
WHERE "ALUMNO"."COD_ALU" = "NOTAS"."COD_ALU" GROUP BY "ALUMNO"."NOM_ALU", "ALUMNO"."APE_ALU" ORDER BY AVG( "NOTAS"."NOT_NOT" ) DESC

Answer (score 0):

SELECT "ALUMNO"."NOM_ALU", "ALUMNO"."APE_ALU", AVG( "NOTAS"."NOT_NOT" ) FROM "ALUMNO", "NOTAS" 
WHERE "ALUMNO"."COD_ALU" = "NOTAS"."COD_ALU" GROUP BY "ALUMNO"."NOM_ALU", "ALUMNO"."APE_ALU" ORDER BY AVG( "NOTAS"."NOT_NOT" ) DESC

[SOLUTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpWxG.png)